# How do I use a variable from a function of a cpp file on another function in anotehr cpp file?

Tags: c++, tetris

I'm making a tetris game and I can't figure out how to use the variable that calculates the score in another file where it is going to print the score to the screen. Here is the code:

```
//board.cpp
//Here is the variable mScore that i want to use

/* 
======================================                                  
Delete all the lines that should be removed
====================================== 
*/
int Board::DeletePossibleLines ()
{
     int Score = 0;
     for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_HEIGHT; j++)
     {
         int i = 0;
         while (i < BOARD_WIDTH)
         {
            if (mBoard[i][j] != POS_FILLED) break;
            i++;
         }

         if (i == BOARD_WIDTH)
         {
             DeleteLine(j);
             Score++;
         }
     }
     int mScore = Score;
     return mScore;
 }
```

It is declared in a class in Board.h as this:

```
//Board.h
class Board
    {
    public:
    int DeletePossibleLines();
    }
```

And i want to use it in IO.cpp, i treid this:

```
//IO.cpp
#include "Board.h"

void IO :: text()
    {
    //I call the class
    Board *mBoard
    //I attribute the function to a variable and i get an error
    int Score = *mBoard -> DeletePossibleLines;
    }
```

The error i get is "Error C2276: '*' : illegal operation on bound member function expression" on the IO.cpp

So i want Score from IO.cpp to be equal to mScore from Board.cpp

Here's also what I tried and failed if it helps:

I tried to declare the class in IO.cpp like this:

```
  //IO.cpp
  Board mBoard
  mBoard.DeletePossibleLines
```

But got an error that says "Expression must have a class type"

I also tried putting everything in the same file, but I failed as well, plus each file has more that a hundred lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call the function, not assign the function's pointer. Use something like this:

```
int Score = mBoard -> DeletePossibleLines();
//                                       ^^ note these!
```

This assumes a valid `mBoard` pointer which is not present in the code you posted.

Comment: I followed your instruction but now i get this 

Unhandled exception at 0x00FF6CD0 in tetris_tutorial_sdl.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: @theodorekaradimas That means the pointer is *not* initialized. The problem you asked about is solved, but you now need to solve the next problem: Have one instance of `Board` and call methods on it. Your second option (`Board mBoard; mBoard.DeletePossibleLines();`) would solve the immediate problem of the unhandled exception, but it will not work in the long run as you apply the algorithm to a local board and you can not really create a working games based on that.

Answer (score 0):

`mBoard` is a pointer to a `Board` object. Assuming it's initialized properly (which is missing from your snippet), you don't need to derefenrence it in order to call its methods. Additionally, you are missing brackets (`()`) to signify it's a method call and not a public data member:

```
int Score = mBoard -> DeletePossibleLines();
```